# How to read Java object after anypoint MQ subscriber

Tags: dataweave, mule4, anypoint-mq

I am publishing the simple java payload into the anypointMQ publisher.

## Input payload to anypointMQ publisher

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
key1 : "value1" ,
key2 : "value2"
}
```

I am receiving the payload from subscriber, I am unable to read the payload. The payload coming as binary format. Please find the attachment. Please help how to read the payload. [image]

After anypointMQ subscriber, I am using the DW code as below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.^raw
```

Comment: no luck receiving error below.

ERROR 2023-12-14 12:39:27,460 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [test].mq-pocFlow1.CPU_INTENSIVE @5f7a736c] [processor: ; event: b7f73730-9a4f-11ee-880c-0aa8e13132ed] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Unable to transform String to Base 64 Binary. Reason : `Illegal base64 character 7b`

Comment: Trace:
  at dw::core::Binaries::main (line: 166, column: 5)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0 
import * from dw::core::Binaries 
output application/octet-stream 
---
fromBase64(payload)".
Element               : mq-pocFlow1/processors/0 @ test:convertion.xml:81 (Transform Message)
Element DSL           : <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="c3610b97-d34e-4b33-84d9-26d58d8fdd2a">
<ee:message>
<ee:set-payload><![CDATA[
%dw 2.0 
import * from dw::core::Binaries 
output application/octet-stream 
---
fromBase64(payload)

Comment: ERROR 2023-12-14 13:44:22,800 [[MuleRuntime].uber.06: [test].mq-pocFlow1.CPU_INTENSIVE @6105c11a] [processor: ; event: c9854ce0-9a58-11ee-b559-0aa8e13132ed] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "You called the function 'entrySet' with these arguments: 
  1: Binary ("ewogIGtleTE6ICJ2YWx1ZTEiIGFzIFN0cmluZyB7Y2xhc3M6ICJqYXZhLmxhbmcuU3RyaW5nIn0s...)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Object

Comment: Don't put details into comments. Logs are hard to read. Edit your question to add the information there. The errors mention code that is not in the question also.

Answer (score 1):

The body of an Anypoint MQ message is sent as a string as part of a JSON message. A Java object by default will be serialized in binary format that may be specific to the Java version. In a Mule application you should avoid relying on Java serialization so avoid using Java payloads. Instead use a format that has a textual representation like JSON or XML for objects. If you have to transfer binary data -excluding serialized Java objects- use the toBase64() function of the Binaries module.

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-faq#how-can-i-send-a-java-object-as-a-message